# Github action generationg json payload with env variables

Tags: github-actions

I am having problem generating some basic json that I use to call api for processing. Eg I have:

```
env:
  API: .....
  BRANCH_NAME: ${GITHUB_REF##*/}

- name: call api
    uses: privateaction
    with:
      API: ${{ env.AWS_LAMBDA_NAME }}
      Payload: '{"Name": "${env.BRANCH_NAME}" }'
```

further down I use the same variable as:

```
${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}
```

And there it gets the right branch name and works. But when I use it in the API call in different ways I get: ${env.BRANCH_NAME} as input to the api and ${GITHUB_REF##*/}

I feel like I keep going in circles. The idea is I am going to need a bigger json structure with more fields. But I can't really get it to work with just 1.

I feel like I have tried all combinations of what could be valid eg.
${{env.BRANCH_NAME}} ${env.BRANCH_NAME} $env.BRANCH_NAME etc.

Most likely just something stupid from my side. Would love some help :)

I know the action works. Tried with hardcoded payload eg: '{"Name": "Joshua"}'. So it is something with the variable.

Comment: I don't think you can use this kind of behavior / expression in an input field. Why not creating a step to generate the whole payload, and save it as output or env variable to use only this variable in the action input field?

Comment: @GuiFalourd > Perhaps that is the way to go. Was just hoping I didn't need extra steps.

Comment: Use [`github.ref_name`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) to get the branch name. In shell, use [`GITHUB_REF_NAME`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables) env var. Try: `Payload: '{"Name":"${{github.ref_name}}"}'` or using [`format`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#format) i.e. `Payload: ${{ format('{{"Name":"{0}"}}', github.ref_name) }}` (mind the absence of space after `:` in JSON as that'll break YAML parsing, or you may use a multiline string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I ended up doing to make it work per @GuiFalourd comment was to move payload generation into it's own step like so:

```
- name: Create JSON Payload
    run: echo "JSON_PAYLOAD={\"Name\":\"${{ env.BRANCH_NAME }}\"}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

and use it further down like this:

```
Payload: ${{ env.JSON_PAYLOAD }}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use double curly brace, instead of

```
      Payload: '{"Name": "${env.BRANCH_NAME}" }'
```

use

```
      Payload: '{"Name": "${{env.BRANCH_NAME}" }}'
```

you don't need an extra step to build the payload

**UPDATE**

Seems the issue is the env definition in the `env` section: moving the var definition in a dedicated step will solve the problem. Of course this solution is similar to build the payload in a dedicated step. See this PR https://github.com/mbiagetti/github-action-poc/pull/4/files

Comment: I tried all possible ways of doing it. And could simply not get it to work.

Comment: seems strange to me since I have some working workflow that use the same approach....

Comment: @Mattero Would love to see working sample :D I couldn't get it to work with that approach. Would be much cleaner.

Comment: @Kiksen see my update. TL;TR: my first answer is wrong: btw the issue was with the env declaration but the solution is similar to build the payload in a dedicated step